# Increasing the JTA Transaction Timeout value using WLST with property file

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I want to increase the JTA Transaction Timeout value using WLST and a property file with the key

```
domain.jta.timeout = 350
```

So I run this but nothing happens !

```
C:\wls12130\wlserver\server\bin>java weblogic.WLST -loadProperties increaseJtaTimeout.properties

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline>
```

Comment: Loading the property file is not enough, you have to read values from the property file and call mbeans' methods to set the JTA timeout. You have to write a script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways.

1) from console you can change. login to weblogic console > Click on domain name > click on configuration > JTA > update "Timeout secounds" to whatever value you want.

2) you can set by wlst. for wlst you need to update in online mode. 
 For that you need to connect to Admin server using connect().

1. invoke wlst. run each command individually.

   ```
   connect(d'omainuser', 'domainpassword','t3://adminhost:port') 
   edit() 
   startEdit() 
   cd('/JTA/domainname') 
   setTimeoutSecounds(value) 
   save() 
   activate()
   ```
2. you can put all individual commands in python script and run
   it. invoke wlst and pass the python script as argument.

Comment: > setTimeoutSecounds(value)

Two issues here. Typo in the method name and you should use cmo to invoke it. It should be cmo.setTimeoutSeconds(300)